# How to output lines of a text file in a batch file (Windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file

How to output lines of a text file in a batch file?

E.g.
sample.txt

```
red
blue
green
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the `type` statement:

```
type sample.txt
```